# TinyMCE not showing buttong on some IE clients

Tags: tinymce, webfonts

We have just introduced TinyMCE into our application.  Everything worked fine until we made our first production deployment.  Now we have a few user reporting that they cannot see the button images.

They have sent screenshots: most are just the empty gray background but one shows tiny squares on the buttons.

I cannot duplicate this issue on any of our machines.

All the people with problems are using IE (both 8 and 9).  The users with the problem also have this problem at the tinyMCE website.

I have added the following mimeMaps to my web.config to solve a couple of 404 errors we had.

Can anyone suggest what to look for?
It is difficult when I cannot duplicate the problem.